# Flutter Refresh UI on submit from API call

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to post comment on Api. I can post the comment correctly and it's posting on the api endpoint too. What I want is to refresh the UI after posting the comment, so I can see my latest comment. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

This is the code that's posting the comment on the api:

```
void _postComment() async {
    var data = {
      'content': commentContent,
    };
    var res = await CommentApi().authData(data, widget.post.postId);
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    print(body);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Successful'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Your comment has been added.'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Okay'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                setState(() {
                  textEditingController.clear();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This is CommentApi

```
class CommentApi{
  var token;

  _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token'))['token'];
  }

  authData(data, postID) async {
    await _getToken();
    return await http.post(
        ApiUtil.postComment(postID),
        body: jsonEncode(data),
        headers: _setHeaders()
    );
  }

  _setHeaders() => {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer $token'
  };

}
```

To retrieve the comments

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: widget.post.comments.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _commentsWidget(widget.post.comments[index]);
          },
        ),
```

```
Widget _commentsWidget(PostComment comment) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 55.0),
                child: Text(
                  comment.commentText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using this strategy:

1. Firstly, declare global List variable in your State class that stores current comments fetching from an API
2. Then, use this variable in your ListView.builder
3. Update this variable in setState when your comment is successfully added to API
4. In this case, UI will be updated correctly according to new setted list of comments